# How to I resolve Error: cannot find module ? unable to load js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm trying to rewrite some code in which the the bot loads .js files within a specific folder.
Originally, to access the folder I would load my command files from I would have done the following and repeated the same code to access different folders:

```
fs.readdirSync("../src/Commands/Moderation")
     .filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))
     .forEach(file => {
     const command = require(`../Commands/Moderation/${file}`);
     console.log(`Command ${command.name} loaded`);
     this.commands.set(command.name, command);

    });
```

However, I want a better method than the above. As you can seen in the code above I want to load a js file inside folder called Moderation, bear in mind I have more than one folder containing .js files in folder \Commands.

The second and preferred method I want to try to load commands is giving some issues.
Below is the code of what I want to do, however I'm getting an console error `Error: Cannot find module '../src/Commands/Moderators/colours.js'`. The colours.js file does exist within that directory. I cannot pin point what the issue is here.

```
fs.readdirSync("../src/Commands/").forEach(dir => {
    const commandfiles = fs.readdirSync(`../src/Commands/${dir}/`).filter(f => 
f.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandfiles) {
        const command = require(`../src/Commands/${dir}/${file}`);
        console.log(`Loading  ${command.name}`, "cmd");
        this.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

Project Structure:

```
Users/
Jac/
Desktop/
jacbot/
src/
├─ main.js
├─ Structures/
├─ Commands/ 
│  ├─ Moderation/
│  │   ├─ colours.js
├─ Data/
│  ├─ config.json
├─ Events/
│  ├─ messages.js
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: Sure my project structure is ../src/Commands/Moderation/Files.js

I'm assuming you mean this.

Comment: No, I meant the locations of files for example something like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118644/384655). The error may be because of the path

Comment: @Joe I've added the project structure to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Commands files are in the src directory, you don't need to leave that directory. Your path should be something like `./Commands` or `./Commands/Moderation` if you're running from the main folder

`../` indicates that you're leaving the current directory to go up one
`./` is in the current directory

Comment: Unfortunately after making the amendment to just `./Commands` the error still persists.

Comment: There are no js files in your Commands folder based on the structure so I believe you'd need ``./Commands/Moderation``

Comment: In my second code block is exactly that on this line `const command = require(`./Commands/${dir}/${file}`);`  and `fs.readdirSync("./Commands").forEach(dir => { const commandfiles = fs.readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter(f => f.endsWith('.js'));`

Comment: But the error to the above amended still gives me `Error: Cannot find module './Commands/Moderation/colours.js'` yet the file colours.js does exist in that file.

Comment: Do you have colours.js hardcoded in the path anywhere?

Comment: No, I'm certain it's not hardcoded anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

So after much head scratching I figured out. The issue wasn't to do with the `readdirSync` method but `require` line. It should be `../Commands/${dir}/${file}` opposed to `./Commands/${dir}/${file}`.

The reason is that the code is within a file that is inside another folder within the projects root folder.

Therefore we need to go back one and look for the Commands folder in the root folder. In this case `../` to go back the root folder `./src` and then `/commands/folder/file`.

Here is the corrected code block.

```
fs.readdirSync("./Commands").forEach(dir => {
        const commandfiles = fs.readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for (const file of commandfiles) {
           const command = require(`../Commands/${dir}/${file}`);
           console.log(`Loading  ${command.name}`, "cmd");
           this.commands.set(command.name, command);
```